# Problem while enabling webp on azure app php 7.4 linux

Tags: php, azure, azure-web-app-service, gd, webp

Please I am trying to compile gd with webp on azure web app

apt-get update && apt-get install -y libwebp-dev && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr --with-png-dir=/usr --with-jpeg-dir=/usr --with-webp-dir=/usr && docker-php-ext-install gd

And i am getting this error , I tested it on 7.3 and it is working good

/bin/bash /usr/src/php/ext/gd/libtool --mode=compile cc -I/usr/src/php/ext/gd/libgd -I. -I/usr/src/php/ext/gd -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/usr/src/php
/ext/gd/include -I/usr/src/php/ext/gd/main -I/usr/src/php/ext/gd -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/includ
e/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/include/libpng16  -fstac
k-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_
LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -c /usr/src/php/ext/gd/libgd/gd.c -o libgd/gd.lo
/usr/src/php/ext/gd/libtool: line 1283: libgd/gd.loT: No such file or directory
mkdir libgd/.libs
mkdir: cannot create directory 'libgd/.libs': No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:197: libgd/gd.lo] Error 1